# Database explorer disabled in SQL Assistant

Tags: teradata

I am a new Teradata SQL assistant user. I have used SQL Server Management Studio before.

In the View option, I am unable to toggle the Database Explorer. Please let me know how I can access the databases I add on my SQL assistant.

[image: Database explorer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

once you are connected to the DB on the left side of the window you will see the DB tree hierarchy.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am in no way a tech expert!! I am an intern at a department store corporate office. But after lots of toggling around with buttons, I found out that when I pressed the connection symbol, all I needed to do was put in my corporate password. I had previously been connected with access to the company databases, but my password wasn't saved so all I needed to do was re-put it in. Hope this helps.